# Row animation occurs when specifying UITableViewRowAnimationNone for UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Slow animation simulator testing for my iOS app shows that the first row of my table view is always animated, regardless of how I specify animation for the row.

```
            int insertIdx = 0;
            [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

How can I disable all row animation for a tableview?  This happens with iOS 6.1 and 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first row, you can use `[self.tableView reloadData]` instead of `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` (you can also use reloadData for all the other rows, but insertRowsAtIndexPaths is more efficient).